# Python Reading (floating-point) values one at a time

Tags: python, file, numpy, input

I'd like to fill in a numpy array with some floating-point values coming from a file. The data would be stored like this:

```
0 11
5 6.2 4 6
2 5 3.2 6
7 1.4 5 11
```

The first line gives the first and last index and on the following lines come the actual data. My current approach is to split each data line, use `float` on each part, and store the values in a pre-allocated array, slice by slice. Here is how I do it now:

```
data_file ='data.txt'
# Non needed stuff at the beginning
skip_lines = 0

with open(data_file, 'r') as f:
    # Skip any lines if needed
    for _ in range(skip_lines):
        f.readline()
    # Get the data size and preallocate the numpy array
    first, last = map(int, f.readline().split())
    size = last - first + 1
    data = np.zeros(size)

    beg, end = (-1, 0) # Keep track of where to fill the array
    for line in f:
        if end - 1 == last:
            break
        samples = line.split()
        beg = end
        end += len(samples)
        data[beg:end] = [float(s) for s in samples]
```

Is there a way in Python to read the data values one by one instead?

```
import numpy as np
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
first, last = map(int, f.readline().split())
arr = np.zeros(last - first + 1)
for k in range(last - first + 1):
    data = f.read() # This does not work. Any idea?
    # In C++, it could be done this way: double data; cin >> data
    arr[k] = data
```

**EDIT** The only thing that one can be sure of is that the two first numbers are the first and last index and that the last data row has only the last numbers. There can be **also** other stuff after the data numbers. So one can't just read all the rows after the "first, last" row.

**EDIT 2** Added (working) initial approach (split each data line, use `float` on each part, and store the values in a pre-allocated array, slice by slice) implementation.

Comment: Should we take that `11` at the end of the fourth line to be a kind of end-of-collection marker?

Comment: And how big is your data set?

Comment: @BillBell The 11 is the index of the last entry. For now, it's just used to compute the data size (all the sample files I've seen have 0 as first entry but it could change). The files are not big in general, they can all be read into memory. Typical `first, last` is `0, 1023`

Answer (score 1):

Since your sample has the same number of columns in each row (except the first) we can read it as `csv`, for example with `loadtxt`:

```
In [1]: cat stack43307063.txt
0 11
5 6.2 4 6
2 5 3.2 6
7 1.4 5 11
In [2]: arr = np.loadtxt('stack43307063.txt', skiprows=1)
In [3]: arr
Out[3]: 
array([[  5. ,   6.2,   4. ,   6. ],
       [  2. ,   5. ,   3.2,   6. ],
       [  7. ,   1.4,   5. ,  11. ]])
```

This is easy to reshape and manipulate.  If columns aren't consistent, then we need to work line by line.

```
In [9]: alist = []
In [10]: with open('stack43307063.txt') as f:
    ...:     start, stop = [int(i) for i in f.readline().split()]
    ...:     print(start, stop)
    ...:     for line in f: # f.readline()
    ...:         print(line.split())
    ...:         alist.append([float(i) for i in line.split()])
    ...:         
0 11
['5', '6.2', '4', '6']
['2', '5', '3.2', '6']
['7', '1.4', '5', '11']
In [11]: alist
Out[11]: [[5.0, 6.2, 4.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0, 3.2, 6.0], [7.0, 1.4, 5.0, 11.0]]
```

Replace the `append` with `extend` to collect the values in a flat list instead:

```
alist.extend([float(i) for i in line.split()])
[5.0, 6.2, 4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.2, 6.0, 7.0, 1.4, 5.0, 11.0]
```

`c++` io usually uses streams.  Streaming is possible with Python, but text files are more often read line by line.

```
In [15]: lines = open('stack43307063.txt').readlines()
In [16]: lines
Out[16]: ['0 11\n', '5 6.2 4 6\n', '2 5 3.2 6\n', '7 1.4 5 11\n']
```

a list of lines when can be processed as above.

`fromfile` could also be used, except it looses any row/column structure in the original:

```
In [20]: np.fromfile('stack43307063.txt',sep=' ')
Out[20]: 
array([  0. ,  11. ,   5. ,   6.2,   4. ,   6. ,   2. ,   5. ,   3.2,
         6. ,   7. ,   1.4,   5. ,  11. ])
```

This load includes the first line.  We could skip that with an open and readline.

```
In [21]: with open('stack43307063.txt') as f:
    ...:     start, stop = [int(i) for i in f.readline().split()]
    ...:     print(start, stop)
    ...:     arr = np.fromfile(f, sep=' ')        
0 11
In [22]: arr
Out[22]: 
array([  5. ,   6.2,   4. ,   6. ,   2. ,   5. ,   3.2,   6. ,   7. ,
         1.4,   5. ,  11. ])
```

`fromfile` takes a `count` parameter as well, which could be set from your `start` and `stop`. But unless you just want to read subset it isn't needed.

Comment: The file format is not so clear about the column widths, so we must assume that the columns aren't consistent. The sample files I have have 10 numbers for each row but I prefer not to generalize on that. The only thing that one can be sure of is that the two first numbers are the first and last index and that the last data row has only the last numbers. There can be also other stuff after the data numbers.

Comment: The readline with list extend gives you most control.  If there are non-numbers in a line you will have to filter those out.

Comment: There can't be non-numbers in a row as long as one's reading from `first` entry to `last` entry. However, there can be other stuff starting from the row following the row which contains the `last` number

Comment: Then I'd put the `readline` in a while loop - read until the list is long enough and then break.

Comment: So you mean, build the whole list of numbers first in a while loop? Is your suggestion close to my initial approach (see my edit, I put an implementation) or is it something different? Would you mind adding it in your answer?

Comment: Actually, your `np.fromfile` suggestion with the `count` parameter makes it easy to load the whole data block as we know the number of data samples to be read. Does the `sep` parameter support regexps (say if there are tabs and multiple spaces cropping up)?

Answer (score 1):

Assumes only that the first two numbers represent the indices of the values required from the numbers that follow. Varying numbers of numbers can appear in the first or subsequent lines. Won't read tokens beyond `last`.

```
from io import StringIO
sample = StringIO('''3 11 5\n 6.2 4\n6 2 5 3.2 6 7\n1.4 5 11''')
from shlex import shlex
lexer = shlex(instream=sample, posix=False)
lexer.wordchars = r'0123456789.'
lexer.whitespace = ' \n'
lexer.whitespace_split = True

def oneToken():
    while True:
        token = lexer.get_token()
        if token:
            token = token.strip()
            if not token:
                return
        else:
            return
        token = token.replace('\n', '')
        yield token

tokens = oneToken()

first = int(next(tokens))
print (first)

last = int(next(tokens))
print (last)

all_available = [float(next(tokens)) for i in range(0, last)]
print (all_available)

data = all_available[first:last]
print (data)
```

Output:

```
3
11
[5.0, 6.2, 4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.2, 6.0, 7.0, 1.4, 5.0]
[6.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.2, 6.0, 7.0, 1.4, 5.0]
```

Comment: Interesting! (As a side note, if you have `first, last == 3, 11`, the number of samples you have/need to read should be 9. But it's easy to change). So your approach is to recreate a number parser from scratch. I have two follow-up questions: 1. Why use shlex and not a plain regex? 2. Your approach is nearly exactly what I was looking for. But isn't there a more straightforward way to consume these numbers from the (file)stream instead of creating a token consumer **from scratch**?

Comment: 1. I offered three answers to a question similar to yours some days ago. One of the answers involved `shlex`. Consequently it's near the front of my mind. 2. There could be.

Comment: Could you please give a link to that other thread? I checked some of your answers (great job, BTW!) but couldn't find the one related to mine. For point number 2. I would have expected that consuming the file stream one token at a time would be straightforward but apparently, the Python philosophy is a little bit different. Even the builtin `input` function expects and reads a **whole** line. Thank you for this input. I didn't expect going so low level for this kind of task. That's heavy hammer, to be used with caution ;) We're so spoiled with all the good libraries and builtin functions.

Comment: By the way, talking about hammers and caution, the wordchar should include `-` and `eE` ...

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` will give you the remaining numbers as a string. You'll have to `split` them and `map` to `float`.

```
import numpy as np
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
first, last = map(int, f.readline().split())
arr = np.zeros(last - first + 1)

data = map(float, f.read().split())
```

Comment: Hi, I know that `f.read()` would get all the remaining **content** in one big sweep. I showed that to have a running example. But in general `read` wouldn't do it as one can't easily know beforehand the `size` to be read for the following number in `f.read(size)`. Worse, there can be/are other contents after the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Python works fast with string processing. So you can try to solve this problem of reading with two delimiters. Reduce it to one delimiter and then read (Python 3.):

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = np.loadtxt(StringIO(''.join(l.replace(' ', '\n') for l in open('tata.txt'))),delimiter=' ',skiprows=2)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Data-type is float by default.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to let `loadtxt` load the file as a (3,4) array (skipping the first line).  It can be reshaped if needed.  Assuming that whole file has a consistent number of columns in all rows.

Comment: The file structure is not so clear cut and could change.